# An annulus in $\mathbb R^2$ is path connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $A = \{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2: a \leq (x-c)^2+(y-d)^2 \leq b\}$ for given $a,b,c, d$ real numbers. I want to show that $A$ is path-connected.

How can I do that?

I know that every open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that is connected is path connected. But this is obviously not open so I cannot use that. Then I thought of multiple cases. If we take arbitrary $x$ and $y$ and draw the line between them and they do not intersect with the circle centred at $(c,d)$ then we can obviously draw a line between the points which is still in the set, so we can then define the function. I am stuck on the other case.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I know that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is connected is path connected. But this is obviously not open so I cannot use that. Then I thought of multiple cases. If we take arbitrary x and y and draw the line between them and they do not intersect with the circle centred at (c,d) then we can obviously draw a line between the points which is still in the set, so we can then define the function. I am stuck on the other case.

Comment: Don’t get so tied up in theory that you forget easy, elementary approaches: it’s straightforward to write down an explicit path from one point to another that goes radially to the outer boundary, say, then around the boundary, then radially inward (if necessary). It’s *very* straightforward if you follow the suggestion in @Seirios’s answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set $S:=[0,2\pi]\times[a,b]$ is path-connected, being a product of path-connected sets. The annulus $A$ is the image of $S$ under the continuous map $(x,y)\mapsto y\cdot e^{xi}+(c+di)$, where you consider $\mathbb R^2$ as the complex plane.

Comment: Thank you. Short and elegant.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Translate $A$ so that you can suppose $c=d=0$ and use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following set:

$A^\prime=\{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2: a< (x-c)^2+(y-d)^2< b\}$

i.e. exactly your set but with $<$ instead of $\le$. This set is open and connected, so by your comments it's path connected.

Show that the places in your set but not in mine can easily reach mine by a path.